# Can't Get Program to Compile

Tags: java, string

Pretty new to Java programming, but I'm having trouble getting this to run. I want to read in a word using the `StringBuffer` class, then reverse it. I am fairly unfamiliar with importing Java libraries, so I'm not sure if I did that correctly. Either way, this is what I have. I tried to compile it (I'm working in the Terminal), but got a few compiler errors. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util;
import java.io;

public class HW1A {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
     printBackwards();
  }

  public static void printBackwards (String[] args) {
     StringBuffer backwards = new StringBuffer(args);
     System.out.println(backwards.reverse());
  }

}
```

I get the following complier errors:

HW1A.java:1: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class util
location: package java
import java.util;
           ^
HW1A.java:2: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class io
location: package java
import java.io;

Thanks.

Comment: What errors did you get and on which lines?

Comment: can you put the error messages into the question please. It will help people  who search for those in the future.

Comment: Please tag as homework if it is.

Comment: Use an IDE, for goodness' sake. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577055/classes-not-seeing-each-other-in-jsp/4577160#4577160

Comment: Really, listen to Blessed Geek and download one of the free IDE's. You will actually learn faster using one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two corrections:

```
import java.io.*;
```

To import everything in java.io.

And:

```
printBackwards(args);
```

To pass `args` to your `printBackwards` method (you declared it correctly, but didn't pass the variable).

Answer (score 8):

Since this is a learning exercise have a look at printBackwards, and ask yourself:

What parameters does it need and what are you passing?

Then look at this and what StringBuffer needs - do these match?

Answer (score 2):

The method `printBackwards` takes a `String[]` as an argument, but you're not passing anything when you call it.

Answer (score 2):

No compilation error... but not sure this is what you want to do...

```
public class HW1A {
      public static void main (String[] args) {
         printBackwards(args);
      }

      public static void printBackwards (String[] args) {
         StringBuffer backwards = new StringBuffer();
         for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
             backwards.append(args[i]);
         }
         System.out.println(backwards.reverse());
      }
}
```

**Parameters:** Hello world!

**Output:** !dlrowolleH

Answer (score 2):

This compiles :

```
public class HW1A {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
     printBackwards(args);
    }

    public static void printBackwards (String[] args) {
     StringBuffer backwards = new StringBuffer(args[0]);
     System.out.println(backwards.reverse());
    }

}
```

But you have to decide if the argument to pass to create the StringBuffer is the first element of the args array.